# edit gvim mouse buttons

Tags: vim

I have a two part question regarding mouse clicks on gvim.

1.) I would like to change my gvim double left mouse click into something similar to the windows environment (ie Notepad, Microsoft Word), wherein it: highlights the current word, and replaces it with whatever I type. This is akin to pressing 'cw' for changeword in vim.

2.) I would like my single mouse click to place a cursor upon the selected text and enter insert mode. Again like how a mouse normally behaves in Windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `behave mswin` or `so $VIMRUNTIME/mswin.vim` so set up a lot of stuff so that it works more like a regular windows program.

The specific setting you are looking for are:

```
set select=mouse
```

this causes the mouse to start select mode instead of visual mode. Select mode causes the selection to be deleted and insert mode to be entered when a printable key is pressed.

As in Prince Goulash's answer

```
nmap <LeftMouse> <LeftMouse>i
```

will turn on a sort of click-to-type mode.

Answer (score 1):

1) `nmap <2-LeftMouse> ciw`

You could use `viw` here, which will visually select the current word, but then you will still have to press `c` to replace it.

2) `nmap <LeftMouse> <Leftmouse>i`

Or replace the `i` with an `a` if you would prefer to append, rather than insert.